# Spring Boot Service fail to run after startup because MySQL Database is not ready yet

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, spring-boot, init.d

I have installed a Spring Boot application at my Ubuntu 16 server as an init.d service to run at system startup automatically 
[as described here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html).

I have also MySQL Database which I need for Spring Boot app. The problem is, application crashes after Spring boot tries to connect to db:

```
2016-09-21 12:54:32.382 ERROR 1384 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
...
2016-09-21 12:54:32.384  WARN 1384 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure
```

I think, this because MySQL database is not ready yet. But this causes complete fail of Spring Boot App.

When I try to start the same service manually again, everything works perfectly.

So, my question is, can I define some kind of init.d dependencies? So my Spring boot app waits until database is ready?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using systemd.

In your link, in the part:

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp
After=mysql.service

[Service]
User=myapp
ExecStart=/var/myapp/myapp.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Change the After line like I show, replacing syslog by mysql.